# char** to char*

Tags: c

SO,

I have a char**; which is essentially a sentence with a pointer to every word in that sentence; i.e.

```
'h''i''\0''w''o''r''l''d''\0''y''a''y''!''\0'
```

I am looking to extract the last char* (yay!) in this case with a function that can accept sentences of varying word amounts and letter counts. Any ideas? Thus far, I have found a few library functions that do similar things but none that do exactly this.

Comment: @MarcB  that wouldn't work, it would take the length of "hi"  which is of length 2-1, which would return "world"   but is dependent on the first word

Comment: then you can't use the standard C string functions and will have to roll your own. exactly how do you plan to keep track of how long this string is, given that the standard C end-of-string delimiter is now actually part of the string?

Comment: I dunno, not my code, as far as I can tell, he can't do it without some convention on end of the sentence, maybe a /0 word or something

Comment: The string you've posted is a `char*`, not a `char**` (`'h''i'` etc. are `char` literals, not strings. Did you mean: `"h""i""\0"`...?)

Comment: So, how does your program know that it's reached the last word? When windows stores strings in this fashion, it uses a double-null to signify the end. Apart from looking at the data with your eyes and deciding that you want to extract "Yay!", how would the program have any certainty that it's extracting what you want?. And actually, if you're talking about char**, wouldn't you have char **theArray[] = { &"hi", &"world", &"yay!" }; ??  Unless you knew it had pointers to three strings, how would you know you wanted theArray[2] ?

Answer (score 3):

When you're assigning the values to the `char **`, how do you keep track of the last word? The answer to your problem relies upon this. You could use a terminal value, eg. a `NULL` value after the last word and then search for the terminal value like `strlen` does, or store the length in a `size_t` variable or a `struct` with a flexible array member (i.e. `struct fubar { size_t size; char *word[]; }`, with some `push_back` function to reallocate the entire object as the array grows, and to increment `size`). Without further information regarding the code you've written so far, I can't determine which one of these applies to you.

Comment: thats what I figured; assuming I don't have a specific value at the end or keep track of strlen there would be no way to do it?

Looks like I will have to modify my code and keep track of len

Comment: +1 for suggesting to zero-terminate the char** by adding one last entry carrying a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper data structure for this. For example:

```
struct sentence {
    size_t word_count;
    char** words;
};
```

Then you'll always be able to get to the last word in O(1) time:

```
struct sentence blah;
// ...
char* last_word = blah.words[blah.word_count - 1];
```